# Using QTextStream stops std::cout working

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Using Qt (v5.15.0) in Visual Studio 2019 with the `Qt VS Tools` extension installed. Simple console application. Below is a simple demonstration of the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <QDebug>

void main()
{
    std::cout << "cout: Line 1\n";
    qDebug() << "qDebug: Line 2";
    std::cout << "cout: Line 3\n";
    QTextStream qts{stdout};
    qts << "QTextStream: Line 4\n";
    qts << "QTextStream: Line 5\n";
    qts.flush();
    qDebug() << "qDebug: Line 6";
    std::cout << "cout: Line 7\n";       // Not printed!
    qDebug() << "qDebug: Line 8";
}
```

Everything is printed except `Line 7`. Comment out the four `QTextStream` lines, and `Line 7` is printed again.

This seems to be related to the `QTextStream` object "capturing" the standard output. How do I get the object to release `stdout` so that `std::cout` starts working again?

Comment: on my computer (visual studio community edition 2019 and QT 5.9.9) this compiles and prints every line including line 7, maybe `std::endl;` at the end of line 7 would do it.

Comment: @user: Thanks, changing `Line7` to `std::cout << "cout: Line 7" << std::endl;` fixes it. That still raises the question why `Line1` works, but `Line 7` does not work?

Comment: Both lines work. The buffer just needs to be flushed.

Comment: @user: If you read the question, when the 4 `QTextStream` lines are commented out, `Line 7` is printed *without requiring the buffer to be flushed*. `QTextStream` is doing something to change the behaviour of `std::cout`.

Comment: I understand that, it is true that when those lines are commented out line 7 is flushed. But line 7 was never guaranteed to be flushed in the first place. It's just that a side effect of having those 4 lines is that line 7 is not flushed, it is neither a bug nor a problem. Is this behaviour a problem in your program ? If it is consider using `unitbuf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my computer (visual studio community edition 2019 and QT 5.9.9) this compiles and prints every line including line 7.
If you want to make sure the buffer is flushed at line 7 you can use :

```
std::cout << "cout: Line 7\n" << std::flush;
```

but you'd have to use it every line you want to be certain to be flushed.
Alternatively, if you want the buffer to be flushed every time you call `std::cout` you could use `unitbuf` :

```
std::cout << std::unitbuf
```

When the unitbuf flag is set, the associated buffer is flushed after each insertion operation.
On your system these 4 `QTextStream` lines have the side effect of not having line 7 flushed by default. On my system these lines don't have this side effect. Because line 7 was never guaranteed to be flushed in the first place, this really isn't a problem.

Comment: Thanks. After a bit of research I've found that adding either `std::cout << std::unitbuf;` or `setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0);` as the first line in the program resolves the issue. Presumably both set the flag in `stdout` to flush the buffer after each insertion operation.